# Simple R plotting alternatives for Python

Tags: python

I'm coming from R and I'm interested in simple, one-liner plotting functions. Matplotlib is a little more involved than what I'm used to. I would like to know if there is a simple, minimal plotting package available for Python.

As an example, in order to plot bar graphs side by side in Python, I must do the following:

```
# set the x-axis spacing.
r1 = np.arange(len(eval(arr1)))
r2 = [x + 0.3 for x in r1]

# create plots
plt.bar(r1, arr1, width = 0.3, color = 'red', edgecolor = 'black')
plt.bar(r2, arr2, width = 0.3, color = 'blue', edgecolor = 'black')
# show plots
plt.show()
```

To do the same in R, I would only write:

```
barplot(rbind(arr1, arr2), beside = TRUE, col = c('red', 'blue'))
```

Comment: check out [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) as a simple wrapper around matplotlib

Comment: I did. I could not find a similar solution there.

Comment: alternatively, if you're a fan of ggplot2 in R, there are python packages which try to recreate ggplot in python

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html

Comment: this site might be of use a well: https://python-graph-gallery.com/barplot/

Comment: ggplot2 is also more involved. I just want simple alternatives to R's core plotting functions.

Comment: Seaborn is probably the simplest, as you can see from the example. Otherwise, if you're too invested in R, you could always try calling R under the hood via the rpy2 package